# d3 v4 Grouped Bar Chart - .data(fn).enter() is empty

Tags: d3.js

I'm using [this mbostock example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967) as a guide, but it's in d3 v3. I've read that in v4, selections have changed, but this doesn't seem to be my issue since the data never changes - this is a static chart (for now).

I've got an array of objects, in which I expect to create a group (`g`) for each object, and two rectangles (`rect`) for each `field1` and `field2` of that object that correlate to the date. I'm able to create the groups, but when I `.data(d => d)` while attempting to make the rectangles, the enter group appears to be empty.

Can someone explain why this is?

[jsfiddle (not working)](https://jsfiddle.net/kevinfunk/5jhrcvbL/5/)

**UPDATE:** [jsfiddle (working)](https://jsfiddle.net/kevinfunk/5jhrcvbL/6/) *– thanks to @gerardo-furtado*

```
var models = [
  {
    "date":"2016-10-13T07:00:00.000Z",
    "field1":19,
    "field2":83
  },
  {
    "date":"2016-10-14T07:00:00.000Z",
    "field1":67,
    "field2":93
  },
  {
    "date":"2016-10-15T07:00:00.000Z",
    "field1":10,
    "field2":56
  },
  {
    "date":"2016-10-16T07:00:00.000Z",
    "field1":98,
    "field2":43
  }
];
models = models.map(i => {
  i.date = new Date(i.date);
    return i;
});

var container = d3.select('body'),
    width = 500,
    height = 300,
    margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    barPadding = .2,
    axisTicks = {qty: 5, outerSize: 0, dateFormat: '%m-%d'};

var svg = container
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

var xScale0 = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]).padding(barPadding);
var xScale1 = d3.scaleBand();
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale0).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat(axisTicks.dateFormat)).tickSizeOuter(axisTicks.outerSize);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(axisTicks.qty).tickSizeOuter(axisTicks.outerSize);

xScale0.domain(models.map(d => d.date));
xScale1.domain(['field1', 'field2']).range([0, xScale0.bandwidth()]);
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(models, d => d.field1 > d.field2 ? d.field1 : d.field2)]);

var date = svg.selectAll(".date")
  .data(models)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "date")
  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${xScale0(d.date)},0)`);

/* Add field1 bars */
var rect = date.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(d => d) // FIXME: the .enter() group seems to contain nothing
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", d => { xScale1('field1') })
  .attr("y", d => { yScale(d.field1) })
  .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", d => {
    return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - yScale(d.field1)
  });

/* Add field2 bars */
// var rect = date.selectAll(".bar")
//  .data(d => d)
//  .enter()
//  .append("rect")
//  .attr("class", "bar")
//  .attr("x", d => { xScale1('field2') })
//  .attr("y", d => { yScale(d.field2) })
//  .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
//  .attr("height", d => {
//    return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - yScale(d.field1)
//  });

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.top - margin.bottom})`)
   .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis")
   .call(yAxis);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D3, `data` has to be an array. If you look at Bostock's example, `layers` is an array of arrays. This is the result of `console.log(layers)`:

```
Array[4]
    0:Array[58]
    1:Array[58]
    2:Array[58]
    3:Array[58]
```

Thus, because `layers` is an array of arrays, when later in the code Bostock writes this:

```
.data(function(d) { return d; })
```

He is passing an array to `data`, which works.

However, in your code, you're passing a object to `data` in your enter selection for `rect`:

> Object {date: Thu Oct 13 2016 18:00:00 GMT+1100, field1: 19, field2: 83}

**Solution**: pass an array to `data`. This is the only change I made:

```
.data(d => [d])
```

Now you have an array:

> [{date:Thu Oct 13 2016 18:00:00 GMT+1100, field1: 19, field2: 83}]

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96d3wtys/

PS: you'll have to adjust the `y` and `height` of your bars.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! A side note: do you know how I can combine lines 59-83? I'm currently drawing one set of bars (field1) and then another (field2). If restructuring the original data makes it easier, that's okay too.

Comment: You can use group elements to avoid redundant code but, as you said, it involves restructuring your data. So, if you don't mind a little repetition, the code seems to be good the way it is right now.